# error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array'

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

```
cv::Mat Cls::conv2(cv::Mat a, cv::Mat filt) {
    cv::Mat result(a.rows,a.cols,a.type());
    cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuInput(a);
    cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuFilter(filt);
    cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuResult;
    cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::Convolution> convolution = cv::cuda::createConvolution();
    convolution->convolve(gpuInput, gpuFilter, gpuResult);
    gpuResult.download(result);
    return result(cv::Range(3, result.rows - 3), cv::Range(3, result.cols - 3));

}
```

I'm currently trying to make conv2d with openCV cuda module. But i get this error. I have tried to change types and channels but it's didn't work. Do you have any suggestion of what the problem might be?

Full error:

`error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'arithm_op'`

Do you have any suggestion of what the problem might be? I've been stuck on this for a long time... Or any other suggestions about convolution in cv::cuda.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: debug this, figure out which line of code throws the exception. [mre]